# How do I access Express.js Cookie in React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, axios

I'm creating E-shop with MERN Stack

[image]

This is my response from the server on Login where you can see, the cookie is SET and it's sent from the Backend.

That means no there shoudln't be problem with BE, but the FE I will need to handle the Cookie on the FE.

How do I access this sent Cookie from Express in the React ?

I have tried something like this:

const handleLogin = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

```
try {
  const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login";
  const data = await axios.post(url, formFields);

  const { user } = data.data;

  // Here I have tried to access it from Headers where I can see it in the attached 
  // picture under Set-Cooki. But inside headers I can only see 
  // Content-Length and Content-Type


  console.log(data.headers);

  // Aswell I have tried react-cookie but docs are not clear enough for me.
  // and this just sets cookie from react, I would like to use cookie from express 
  // and set it like this
  // await setCookie("user", "INSERT_HERE_COOKIE_FROM_EXPRESS.JS", {
  //   path: "/",
  // });

  setCurrentUser(user);
  await resetFormFields();
} catch (error) {
  const data = error.response.data;
  !data.error
    ? alert(`${data.message}`)
    : alert(`${data.message}: ${data.error}`);
}
```

};

Thank you for any answers, I'm sure it's not that hard as I think and it's few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

As I see on your screenshot - you use express with httpOnly cookies:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies -

> A cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript Document.cookie API; it's only sent to the server. For example, cookies that persist in server-side sessions don't need to be available to JavaScript and should have the HttpOnly attribute. This precaution helps mitigate cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

And I think you don't want to use nonsecure cookies in your E-shop - so you can't access it, but you can use custom headers, so on your frontend it will be like:

> fetch('/myapi').then(response => console.log(response.headers.get('myCustomHeader')));

Comment: Hello Andrei, Thank you for the answer ! :) 

I thought I must be missing something but couldn't understand properly what they trying to say. The article you showed explains it very well. 

One thing is still not clear. If i'll make my custom cookie on the FE, how can i authenticate it with BE.

Comment: as I mentioned earlier - using of non-httpOnly cookies for auth is a bad decision but if you want so - you can just disable httpOnly feature on your server - like this

`app.use(session({
  cookie:
  {
    httpOnly: false // Sensitive
  }
}))`

Comment: and if you want to use a custom header for auth - you need to implement a middleware for handling it